# Get list of true positives, false positives, false negatives and true negatives with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here is my work :

- I have annotated images of "Living" cells (circa 8.000) and images of "Dead" cells (circa 2.000) (+ 800 and 200 for testing set)
- I am using CNN (with tensorflow and keras) in order to classify images as "Living" or "Dead".
- I trained my model : validation loss = 0.35, recall = 0.81, accuracy = 0.81.

Here is the problem : how can I get the list of images classified as "Living" or "Dead" so I can check them (maybe some of images are not in the right folder ? Or model has issue with specific type of images ?)

Please, could you let me know if you have any clue in order to solve this issue ?

Kindly yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the case of binary classification you can take difference between the vector of true labels and the predicted labels. The difference vector will contain zeros where it classified correctly, -1 for false positives, 1 for false negatives. You can then for example use `np.where` to find the indices of false positives and whatnot.

To get the indices of false positives and false negatives etc you can simply do:

```
import numpy as np 

real = np.array([1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
predicted = np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])

diff = real-predicted
print('diff: ',diff)

# Correct is 0 
# FP is -1 
# FN is 1
print('Correctly classified: ', np.where(diff == 0)[0])
print('Incorrectly classified: ', np.where(diff != 0)[0])
print('False positives: ', np.where(diff == -1)[0])
print('False negatives: ', np.where(diff == 1)[0])
```

output:

```
diff:  [ 0 -1  0  1  0  0  1  0]
Correctly classified:  [0 2 4 5 7]
Incorrectly classified:  [1 3 6]
False positives:  [1]
False negatives:  [3 6]
```

Comment: Hello @Naphat Amundsen ! Thanks for your quick answer. Actually, I have already managed to draw my confusion matrix. However, I would like to know the list of images that my model classified well or wrong (so I can visually check them).

Comment: I am so sorry! I got hotheaded with answering for some reason. I have edited the code now!

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen How can I check this for multiclass classification(4 class)? What would be the diff value in that case?

Comment: @keertikulkarni I would essentially just loop and do the above process respective to each class, and then maybe store the results in a 2d numpy array with shape (n_classes, n_datapoints), then work from that. 

You will basically have multiple diff arrays. I don't know the problem you are attempting to solve so it may not be the most optimal setup for your problem.

You can submit a new question so that I (or somebody else) can properly answer you with code if you would like.

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen Thank you. I have submitted a new question.