# Viewing wrong predictions in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a problem with four classes (labeled as 0,1,2,3). I have a model trained and evaluated. I even have a confusion matrix. But I want to see the image samples which are wrongly classified, mainly FP and FN, so that I have an idea for which samples model has an issue in classifying.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893001/get-list-of-true-positives-false-positives-false-negatives-and-true-negatives/61893463?noredirect=1#comment114812874_61893463) I showed a way to do it for binary case. My idea for your problem is to find FP and FN respective to each class. So what I want to do is

1. For each class **cls** do

   1. Set all labels that are **cls** to 1
   2. Set all labels that are NOT **cls** to 0
   3. Now we have turned the problem into a "binary classification" respective to **cls**

      - Obtain FP and FN (see the linked SO answer)

Code:

```py
import numpy as np 

real = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,3])
predicted = np.array([1,1,0,2,2,1,0,0,2,3,3,1])

classes = np.array([0,1,2,3])

def get_dummy_values(a: np.ndarray, cls: int):
    temp = a.copy()
    mask = (temp == cls)
    temp[mask] = 1
    temp[~mask] = 0
    return temp

diffs = np.empty((len(classes), len(real)), dtype=np.int)
for i, cls in enumerate(classes):
    dum_real = get_dummy_values(real, cls)
    dum_pred = get_dummy_values(predicted, cls)
    
    diffs[i] = dum_real - dum_pred

print(f'{f" Diffs ":=^40}')
print(diffs, end='\n\n')

for diff, cls in zip(diffs, classes):
    print(f'{f" For class {cls} ":=^40}')
    print('False positives: ', np.where(diff == -1)[0])
    print('False negatives: ', np.where(diff == 1)[0], end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
================ Diffs =================
[[ 0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]]

============= For class 0 ==============
False positives:  [2]
False negatives:  [8]

============= For class 1 ==============
False positives:  [ 5 11]
False negatives:  [2]

============= For class 2 ==============
False positives:  [8]
False negatives:  [5]

============= For class 3 ==============
False positives:  []
False negatives:  [11]
```

Note: Assuming your model predicts "mostly correct", the diffs matrix is very sparse, so it may be preferable to use more memory efficient data structures for this task (in case you have a lot of labels).